# Find all listed items in another list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to write a formula for a conditional formatting rule.

The rule needs to trigger if any of the items in a list do not exist in another list.

The following rule is similar but will only work for single values, for example if cell `U18` contains `A,B,C` the condition will trigger if cell `V18` contains anything other than `A`, `B` or `C`.

```
=IF(LOWER(LEFT(U18,LEN(V18)+1))=LOWER(V18)&",",FALSE,IF(LOWER(RIGHT(U18,LEN(V18)+1))=","&LOWER(V18),FALSE,IF(IFERROR(FIND(","&LOWER(V18)&",",LOWER(U18)),0)>0,FALSE,TRUE)))
```

I need a formula that will return `TRUE` if *any* of the comma-delimited values in `V18` do not occur in the comma-delimited list in `U18`.

The following should all return `FALSE`:

```
U18                V18
A,B,C              A,B
A,B,C              A,C
A,B,C              B,C
A,B,C              A
A,B,C              B
```

The following should return `TRUE`

```
U18                V18
A,B,C              X
A,B,C              A,X
A,B,C              A,X,B,C
A                  B
```

There is also a formula [listed here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/654920-match-comma-delimited-values-cell-against-individual-values-column.html#6) that looks like it almost does what I need but over multiple rows,unfortunately I haven't been able to adapt it.

I'm going to keep looking and I'll post my results if I get there, but if anyone can help I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Not possible in this situation unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=OR(SUMPRODUCT(N(1-ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(V18,",",REPT(" ",LEN(V18))),LEN(V18)*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&1+LEN(V18)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(V18,",",""))))-1)+1,LEN(V18)))&",",","&U18&",")))))
```

****Amended ROW portion so as to be compatible as a CF rule.**

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks - I'm not familiar with some of those functions so I'll take time to get to grips with them.

Comment: @pnuts Good point, and thanks. I forgot that this would be inadmissable in CF. Will correct the ROW portion in my post so that it is. Just means a touch more volatility, unfortunately.